# can we append the string with a variable in the ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

```
<div ng-repeat="data in assets">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="text"+{{$index}}/>
</div>
```

here I want to generate different ng-models for each checkbox

Answer (score 4):

You can use alias name "data" and assign "data.isChecked" to ng-model.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in assets">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.isChecked" />
</div>
```

This will add that "isChecked" variables at run time to all objects of "assets" array.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have your `models` in the array you are looping over.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in assets">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.input"/>
</div>
```